# initializing FileInputStream

Tags: java, file, fileinputstream

Why is it asking me to initialize the variable **fin**

```
FileInputStream fin;
File f = new File("C:/Users/NetBeansProjects/QuestionOne/input.txt");
fin = new FileInputStream(f);
```

When trying to close the file

```
fin.close();
```

Comment: where is fin.close()? Is your `fin = new FileInputStream(f);` present in some IF/ELSE block? Also, why not write `FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/NetBeansProjects/QuestionOne/input.txt");`

Comment: Is that your actual code? I don't think it reflects what you are doing actually.

Comment: Post the code with { and }, Java 7 may help with the syntax try( <open resource> ){ <code> } catch(...) {...}

Comment: Hmmmm Initialize fin with null and everything works fine...! I think you are calling fin some where in final block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet this is not exactly the same code that generated the compiler error. Almost sure you declared your variables outside the try-catch-finally block but you initialized them within the try block, which implies the variable may not be initialized in the context of the catch or finally blocks where the compiler error is occurring

For example:

```
FileInputStream fin;
try {
   File f = new File("C:/Users/NetBeansProjects/QuestionOne/input.txt");
   fin = new FileInputStream(f);
} finally {
   //you cannot be sure fin is initialized
   fin.close(); //compiler error
}
```

If you are using JDK 7 perhaps the best way is to use the try with resources to deal with the closing of your stream:

```
File f = new File("C:/Users/NetBeansProjects/QuestionOne/input.txt");
try(FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(f)) {
    //some input stream handlung here
}catch(IOException e){...}
```

Comment: That's true, I didn't know that was the reason! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because more probably you are using this snippet inside of a function, and inside functions variables are not automatically initialized, as they are if they are `instance variables`. If `fin = new FileInputStream(f);` throws an exception, and I think you have `fin.close();` in a `finally` statement (but you didn't put entire code), the compiler doesn't know which is the value of `fin` in order to close it.